# Vue3 component using composition API not rendered in production

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am writing a desktop app using Vue 3 and Electron. I recently added two components using the composition API (`<script setup>`), and all works fine with `npm run electron:serve`.

When I create a production build, the two components written using the composition API do not render, a white screen is being displayed. The components are displayed when the user selects an item from a menu, so until the broken components are selected, everything is fine.

No errors are raised, not in the components' `onErrorCapture`, not in `window.onerror`, not in `vue.config.errorHandler`. The code in `onMounted` is definitely being run, I see REST calls made there in the server log.

If I bundle devtools into the production build, I see that the components are not rendered at all, the router view is empty. No messages in the dev tools console.

Vue is 3.2.37, vue-router 4.0.13, vuex 4.0.2

The source code for the component is ~1000 lines, I created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/m-thielen/909e60564497fcef2df36d6df3c2ad58).

How can I debug this? What's wrong?

Comment: Is there any other component that "works" and uses script setup in your project?

Comment: No. I just converted the two Composition API components to Options API and it works...